# Is it כשב or כבש

Tags: grammar-dikduk

Do both כבש and כשב mean sheep? One pasuk for example is כל חלב שור וכשב while a different example is את הכבש אחד. Translations seem to render both as sheep. So why the difference in spelling? Why the flipped letters? Is each time one is used coming to teach something